# Use php curl to obtain return json

Tags: php, curl

In file A:

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://adomain.com/test.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

In file B:

```
<?php
    $json['message'] = 123;
    return json_encode($json);  
?>
```

When run file A in browser, I expect I shall see a returned json array from file B, however I just can see it displayed "NULL". Actually what's wrong with it? thanks.

Comment: Replace `return` with `echo`. Don't mention it.

Comment: echo is working. But actually my aim is to return something to file A and echo in file A. Is it possible? thanks

Comment: Read my asnwer please.

Comment: If files are on the same server you can always use `require` or `include`. `$val = require('test.php'); var_dump($val);` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curl takes the output of a script. So you script should **output** (`print`, `echo`) something:

```
<?php
    $json['message'] = 123;
    echo json_encode($json);  // not return
?>
```

If your `fileA` is connected with some ajax request, then you should understand the communication between client and server is performed via `strings`, plain simple `strings`.

So if `fileA.php` outputs something which is not a **properly encoded** json string, then you can't treat this output as json. And as a result cannot use `output.message` notation in javascript. So, your script should return **properly encoded** json string (which is already created by `fileB`):

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://adomain.com/test.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $result;   // here, response from fileB which is already json
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: I used to use jquery $.post (as file A) to post something to file B, and return a json_encode($json) back to file A. In file A, I can selectively echo output.message (instead of the whole lengthy json). So, curl cannot achieve this effect, am I correct? thanks

Comment: What effect? Why do you show some php code and then tell about jquery?

Comment: $.post('/process.php',
    { subscribe:$('#subscribe').val(),token:'0ade9837ac2e81912468745f980fa19d'},
function (output){
    if(!output.result){
        $('#'+ output.class_name).addClass('error').next('.error-msg').html(output.error_msg).css('display','block');;
    }
},'json');

Comment: the json from file B is output. I can easily use output.name, output.message to pick what I want from the json

Comment: __NEVER__ write your codes in a comment. They're unreadable. Also see my update,

Comment: so, if json_encode($json) is not the proper json format, how shall I package the $json['message'] in file B to be a proper json? thanks

Comment: `fileB` creates __properly formatted json string__.